# How to create a 3D X,Y,Z array from 2D faces so that contiguity between points is preserved

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, mesh

I'm trying to implement an algorithm that from six 2-D matrices of X,Y,Z points store them in a 3D matrix of X,Y,Z points in such a manner that their connectivity is preserved. An example will clarify the problem.

I've to represent with three 3-D matrices

```
( M3D_X(:,:,:), M3D_Y(:,:,:),M_3D_Z(:,:,:) )
```

an hexahedral region of space. Of that hexahedral region will be known only its faces, stored in three 2-D matrices

```
( [face1_x(:,:,:),face1_y(:,:,:),face1_z(:,:,:)], [face2_x.....]....,],...,[...,face6_Z(:,:,:)] )
```

The only information known about connectivity between faces is that face_i have a side in common with face_j. It isn't given which side is in common.
So,how to store the 2-D matrices in the 3-D matrix so that contiguity between faces is preserved ?
Just to clarify, the interior of the hexahedral region will be created with 3-D transfinite interpolation.

Example ( with only two faces instead of six):

```
! []-->matrix ,--> column separator ;--> row separator 
! face_i_x= [p11_x, p12_x,..,p1n_x;
             ....................
             pm1_x,..........,pmn_x]

face1_x = [0.0,0.5,1.0;
           0.0,0.5,1.0;
           0.0,0.5,1.0]

face1_y = [0.0,0.0,0.0;
           0.5,0.5,0.5;
           1.0,1.0,1.0]

face1_z = [0.0,0.0,0.0;
           0.0,0.0,0.0;
           0.0,0.0,0.0]


face2_x = [0.0,0.5,1.0;
           0.0,0.5,1.0;
           0.0,0.5,1.0]

face2_y = [1.0,1.0,1.0;
           1.0,1.0,1.0;
           1.0,1.0,1.0]

face2_z = [0.0,0.0,0.0;
           0.5,0.5,0.5;
           1.0,1.0,1.0]

cube3D_x = (:,:,:)
cube3D_y = (:,:,:)
cube3D_z = (:,:,:)
```

face1 represent the face at z=0 of the unit cube. face2 represents the face at y=1.0 of the unit cube. To retain the simplicity of this example I will not consider face3,..,face6. Now I need to create a 3D matrix to representing the unit cube.
I can start like this

```
cube3D_x(1,:,:)=face1_x
cube3D_y(1,:,:)=face1_y
cube3D_z(1,:,:)=face1_z
```

but then the second (and subsequent insertion must be handled with special care because
face1 has a side in common with face2 (the edge at y=1.0, z=0.0).
How to insert the second face in the cube ?

For more clarity here is a python script for better visualization of the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

face1x=np.array( [ [0.0,0.4,0.6,1.0] , [0.0,0.4,0.6,1.0] , [0.0,0.4,0.6,1.0],[0.0,0.4,0.6,1.0] ])

face1y=np.array( [ [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3], [0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]])

face1z=np.array( [ [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]] )



face2x=np.array( [ [0.0,0.4,0.6,1.0] , [0.0,0.4,0.6,1.0],[0.0,0.4,0.6,1.0] , [0.0,0.4,0.6,1.0],[0.0,0.4,0.6,1.0] ])

face2y=np.array( [ [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0], [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]] )

face2z=np.array( [ [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3],[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5] ,[0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]])

# because face2 is stored with arbitrary direction of indices, just simulate this randomness with some flipping and rotation

np.flip(face2x)
np.flip(face2y)
np.flip(face2z)

np.rot90(face2x)
np.rot90(face2y)
np.rot90(face2z)

# now plot the two faces
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_wireframe(face1x,face1y,face1z,color='b')

ax.plot_wireframe(face2x,face2y,face2z,color='r')
plt.show()
```

Also : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grid
I'm not interested in performance.
Thank you very much.

----edit---
The same problem can be posed with lines instead of faces and faces instead of 3D volumes.

```
line1 = [1,2,3]
line2 = [5,4,3]
line3 = [5,6,7]
line4 = [9,8,7]
face= matrix(3,3)
```

One can start with

```
face(1,:)= line1
```

and he obtains

```
face = [1,2,3 ;
        *,*,* ;
        *,*,*  ]
```

now if the line2 is inserted like this

```
face(:,3)=line2
```

the result will be

```
face = [1,2,5 ;
        *,*,4 ;
        *,*,3 ]
```

when the correct solution is

```
face(:,3)= reverse(line2)
```

(because point 3 is in common with line1 and line2 ) to obtain

```
face = [1,2,3 ;
        *,*,4 ;
        *,*,5 ]
```

Hope this makes the problem clearer.

Comment: You can use the unit cube. Save its faces in 2-D matrices and rotate them or swap their indices to make their storage order random. However, how can I provide such dataset ? I'll edit the question.

Comment: No code is required, just an algorithm or at least some suggested reading. I searched a lot on the web and found nothing on this problem.

Comment: Sorry, no. It is a matrix with just integers stored, in this example you cam think of them as points IDs. Just to explain that on the edges of the 3D matrix the point IDs of faces must coincide. I'm editing the answer with a more practical example. thanks

Comment: The 2-D matrices represent a 2-D structured mesh of a surface. face1 represents a 2-D structured mesh of the face (who lies in space!) z=0 of the unit cube. "so face1 = face1_x+face1_y+face1_z is set of 3x3=9 3D points. where eachpoint has the same matrix position along the x,y,z matrices" yes! Unfortunately 3-D plots are no simple but I'll try. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grid

Comment: OK I get it now You should edit this info into your questions others to see ... not everyone reads all the comments... Now the 3D matrices will be `3x3x3` = 27 points and represent volume? or its still a surface (in which case what is the resolution of the matrix)?

Comment: The 3D matrix represents a volume. The interior of this volume is obtained from boundaries with transfinite interpolation!  I'll edit with a python script to plot the surfaces, thanks

Comment: Now finally back to your problem. So you have a set of 2D grids (3D planar surfaces) representing regular grid surface topology (is it always square/rectangles)? and want to convert that into set of 3D volumes with the same grid resolution ... so extract the grid coordinates and construct new topology ... regardless of the lower dimensionality set

Comment: Always quadrilaterals. "so extract the grid coordinates and construct new topology ... regardless of the lower dimensionality set " It's like that. I want to construct a 3D volume structured mesh of hexahedral cells starting from known boundaries of this volume (thanks to Transfinite interpolation=TFI). But TFI operate on a 3D matrix so the boundaries of this matrix must be filled with the stored faces that I've in main memory. The 2-D example I've added clarify the problem in 2-D with lines instead of faces.

Comment: if you create the set in some topology order adding new dimensionality is just one for loop on top of that and the connectivity should not change ... you just do not use the `N-1` set only its set of coordnates (not points just coordinates .. like `0.0,0.5,1.0` and do N nested for loops creating the GRID)

Comment: Could you elaborate please ? I don't get what you mean by 'some topology order'. All I have is faces stored in 2-D matrices (flipped or rotated in memory, who knows, see python script example) and a function that returns true or false if face_i is connected to face_j or not.

Comment: have to start coocking rigth now ... I do not code in Python but I can bust example in C++ latter

Comment: thanks. C++ will be ok.

Comment: I got the 2D surface grid working now just to be sure before coding the 3D grid The target is 3D matrix so `grid[i][j][k]` and it stores the grid points of some "cube" corresponding to the 2D grid surface ... so if the 2D grid surface has 6 faces with resolutions `2x3 + 2x3 + 2x2 +2x2  + 3x2 + 3x2` points the 3D would hold entire volume (so 2*2*3 points)?

Comment: Exactly. I presume 2x3 will be front and back of cube. 2x2 lateral faces and 3x2 up and down.

Comment: I added answer with what I had in mind ... also I used matrix of 3D points instead of having 3 matrices of floats so I do not need to code everything 3 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So If I get it right you got 6x 2D matrices of 3D points representing 6 surfaces of some shape (that connects together) in any flip/mirror/order state between each-other and want to construct single 3D matrix with empty interior (for example point `(0,0,0)` and its surface will contain the 6 surfaces reordered reoriented so their edges match.

As you always have 6 3D surfaces with 2D topology your 3D topology can be fixed which simplifies things alot.

1. **define 3D topology**

   It can be any I decided to use this one:

   ```
                           -------------
                          /           /
                         /     5     /
                      y /           /------
                       -------------      |
                       x      |           |
                              |     3     |
           /|                 |           |          /|
          / |                 |           |         / |
         /  |               y -------------        /  |
        |   |                 x                   |   |
        | 0 |                                     | 1 |
        |  /                                      |  /
        | /    -------------                      | /
       y|/x    |           |                     y|/x
               |           |
               |     2     |
               |           |------------
               |           |          /
             y -------------   4     /
               x     y /            /
                       -------------
                       x
   ```

   The numbers `0..5` represent your face (surfaces/faces f0,f1,...f5) index and `x,y` index origin and direction within each 2D matrix.
2. **convert your 6 surfaces to match topology**

   You will need 2 arrays of 6 values. One telling if input matrix is already used in topology (`us[6]`) and the other holding index of input surface mapped to topology `f0...f5` (`id[6]`). At start set all to `-1`. The `us` can hold also the reverse of `id` if needed.

   The first face `f0` can be hardcoded as first input surface as is so

   ```
   id[0]=0;
   us[0]=0;
   ```

   Now its just a matter of going through all edges of `f0` and find matching edge in all unused yet surfaces. So each surface has 4 edges but each edge have 2 possible directions. so that is 8 edge tests per face.

   Once matching edge is found we need to orient the matching face so it matches our selected topology. So we need to mirror x, mirror y and or swap x/y.

   This will obtain `f2,f3,f4,f5`.

   Now just take any of the new found faces and find `f0` by matching its shared edge. Again orient `f0` so it matches topology.
3. **copy surfaces into 3D matrix**

   so allocate 3D matrix size (obtained from resolutions of `f0(x,y),f2(x)` and now just copy all the `f0..f5` to their location in matrix... You can fill up the interior points with `(0,0,0)` or interpolate between the surfaces...

**Here small C++/VCL/OpenGL example:**

**arrays.h** 1D/2D/3D containers

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _arrays_h
#define _arrays_h
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// inline safety constructors/destructors add this to any class/struct used as T
T()     {}
T(T& a) { *this=a; }
~T()    {}
T* operator = (const T *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
//T* operator = (const T &a) { ...copy... return this; }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
template <class T> class array1D
    {
public:
    T       *dat;   // items array
    int     nx;     // allocated size
    array1D()   { dat=NULL; free(); }
    array1D(array1D& a) { *this=a; }
    ~array1D()  { free(); }
    array1D* operator = (const array1D *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    array1D* operator = (const array1D &a)
        {
        int x;
        allocate(a.nx);
        for (x=0;x<nx;x++) dat[x]=a.dat[x];
        return this;
        }
    T& operator[] (int x){ return dat[x]; }
    void free()
        {
        if (dat!=NULL) delete[] dat;
        nx=0; dat=NULL;
        }
    int  allocate(int _nx)
        {
        free();
        dat=new T[_nx];
        nx=_nx;
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T> class array2D
    {
public:
    T       **dat;  // items array
    int     nx,ny;  // allocated size
    array2D()   { dat=NULL; free(); }
    array2D(array2D& a) { *this=a; }
    ~array2D()  { free(); }
    array2D* operator = (const array2D *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    array2D* operator = (const array2D &a)
        {
        int x,y;
        allocate(a.nx,a.ny);
        for (x=0;x<nx;x++)
         for (y=0;y<ny;y++)
          dat[x][y]=a.dat[x][y];
        return this;
        }
    T* operator[] (int x){ return dat[x]; }
    void free()
        {
        if (dat!=NULL)
            {
            if (dat[0]!=NULL) delete[] dat[0];
            delete[] dat;
            }
        nx=0; ny=0; dat=NULL;
        }
    int  allocate(int _nx,int _ny)
        {
        free();
        dat=new T*[_nx];
        dat[0]=new T[_nx*_ny];
        nx=_nx; ny=_ny;
        for (int x=1;x<nx;x++) dat[x]=dat[x-1]+ny;
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T> class array3D
    {
public:
    T       ***dat;     // items array
    int     nx,ny,nz;   // allocated size
    array3D()   { dat=NULL; free(); }
    array3D(array3D& a) { *this=a; }
    ~array3D()  { free(); }
    array3D* operator = (const array3D *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    array3D* operator = (const array3D &a)
        {
        int x,y,z;
        allocate(a.nx,a.ny,a.nz);
        for (x=0;x<nx;x++)
         for (y=0;y<ny;y++)
          for (z=0;z<nz;z++)
           dat[x][y][z]=a.dat[x][y][z];
        return this;
        }
    T* operator[] (int x){ return dat[x]; }
    void free()
        {
        if (dat!=NULL)
            {
            if (dat[0]!=NULL)
                {
                if (dat[0][0]!=NULL) delete[] dat[0][0];
                delete[] dat[0];
                }
            delete[] dat;
            }
        nx=0; ny=0; nz=0; dat=NULL;
        }
    int  allocate(int _nx,int _ny,int _nz)
        {
        int x,y;
        free();
        dat=new T**[_nx];
        dat[0]=new T*[_nx*_ny];
        dat[0][0]=new T[_nx*_ny*_nz];
        nx=_nx; ny=_ny; nz=_nz;
        for (x=1;x<nx;x++) dat[x]=dat[x-1]+ny;
        for (x=0;x<nx;x++)
         for (y=0;y<ny;y++)
          dat[x][y]=dat[0][0]+(x*ny*nz)+(y*nz);
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[gl_simple.h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) just simple OpenGL

**parametric_grid.h** this is the main source you need to digest

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _parametric_grid_h
#define _parametric_grid_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "arrays.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct point
    {
    float x,y,z;
    point()     {}
    point(point& a) { *this=a; }
    ~point()    {}
    point* operator = (const point *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //point* operator = (const point &a) { ...copy... return this; }
    bool point::operator==(const point &a)
        {
        float d;
        d =(x-a.x)*(x-a.x);
        d+=(y-a.y)*(y-a.y);
        d+=(z-a.z)*(z-a.z);
        return (d<=0.001);
        }
    bool point::operator!=(const point &a)
        {
        float d;
        d =(x-a.x)*(x-a.x);
        d+=(y-a.y)*(y-a.y);
        d+=(z-a.z)*(z-a.z);
        return (d>0.001);
        }
    };
typedef array1D<float>  param[3];   // parametrers <0,1>
typedef array2D<point>  surface[6]; // surface
typedef array3D<point>  volume;     // volume
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void swap_xy(array2D<point> &f)
    {
    int ix,iy;
    array2D<point> f0;
    f0=f;
    f.allocate(f0.ny,f0.nx);
    for (ix=0;ix<f.nx;ix++)
     for (iy=0;iy<f.ny;iy++)
      f.dat[ix][iy]=f0.dat[iy][ix];
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void mirror_x(array2D<point> &f)
    {
    int ix0,ix1,iy;
    point p;
    for (ix0=0,ix1=f.nx-1;ix0<ix1;ix0++,ix1--)
     for (iy=0;iy<f.ny;iy++)
      { p=f.dat[ix0][iy]; f.dat[ix0][iy]=f.dat[ix1][iy]; f.dat[ix1][iy]=p; }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void mirror_y(array2D<point> &f)
    {
    int ix,iy0,iy1;
    point p;
    for (ix=0;ix<f.nx;ix++)
     for (iy0=0,iy1=f.ny-1;iy0<iy1;iy0++,iy1--)
      { p=f.dat[ix][iy0]; f.dat[ix][iy0]=f.dat[ix][iy1]; f.dat[ix][iy1]=p; }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void surface2volume(volume &v,surface &s)   // normalize surface and convert it to volume
    {
    point p;
    float *pp=(float*)&p;
    int ix,iy,iz,nx,ny,nz,mx,my,i,j,k,id[6],us[6];

    // find which surface belongs to which face f0..f5 and store it to id[]
    // also mirror/rotate to match local x,y orientations
    id[0]=0; us[0]=0;                   // first face hard coded as 0
    for (i=1;i<6;i++) id[i]=-1;         // all the rest not known yet
    for (i=1;i<6;i++) us[i]=-1;         // unused
    nx=s[0].nx;
    ny=s[0].ny;

    for (iy=0,j=id[0],k=4,i=1;i<6;i++)  // find f4 so it share f0(iy=0) edge
     if (us[i]<0)                       // only in unknonw yet surfaces
        {
        mx=s[i].nx-1;
        my=s[i].ny-1;
        if ((s[j].nx==s[i].nx)&&(s[j].ny==s[i].ny)) // try x,y matched
            {
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   ix][   iy]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                                 swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   ix][my-iy]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                 mirror_y(s[i]); swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-ix][   iy]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]);                 swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-ix][my-iy]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]); mirror_y(s[i]); swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            }
        if ((s[j].nx==s[i].ny)&&(s[j].ny==s[i].nx)) // try x,y swapped
            {
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   iy][   ix]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                                 break; }
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   iy][my-ix]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                 mirror_y(s[i]); break; }
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-iy][   ix]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]);                 break; }
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-iy][my-ix]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]); mirror_y(s[i]); break; }
            }
        } if (id[k]<0) return;          // fail
    nz=s[id[k]].nx;                     // 3th resolution
    v.allocate(nx,ny,nz);               // allocate volume container

    for (iy=ny-1,j=id[0],k=5,i=1;i<6;i++)// find f5 so it share f0(iy=ny-1) edge
     if (us[i]<0)                       // only in unknonw yet surfaces
        {
        mx=s[i].nx-1;
        my=s[i].ny-1;
        if ((s[j].nx==s[i].nx)&&(s[j].ny==s[i].ny)) // try x,y matched
            {
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   ix][   iy]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                                 swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   ix][my-iy]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                 mirror_y(s[i]); swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-ix][   iy]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]);                 swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-ix][my-iy]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]); mirror_y(s[i]); swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            }
        if ((s[j].nx==s[i].ny)&&(s[j].ny==s[i].nx)) // try x,y swapped
            {
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   iy][   ix]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]);                 break; }
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   iy][my-ix]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]); mirror_y(s[i]); break; }
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-iy][   ix]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                                 break; }
            for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-iy][my-ix]){ ix=-1; break; } if (ix>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                 mirror_y(s[i]); break; }
            }
        } if (id[k]<0) return;          // fail

    for (ix=0,j=id[0],k=2,i=1;i<6;i++)  // find f2 so it share f0(ix=0) edge
     if (us[i]<0)                       // only in unknonw yet surfaces
        {
        mx=s[i].nx-1;
        my=s[i].ny-1;
        if ((s[j].nx==s[i].nx)&&(s[j].ny==s[i].ny)) // try x,y matched
            {
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   ix][   iy]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                                 break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   ix][my-iy]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                 mirror_y(s[i]); break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-ix][   iy]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]);                 break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-ix][my-iy]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]); mirror_y(s[i]); break; }
            }
        if ((s[j].nx==s[i].ny)&&(s[j].ny==s[i].nx)) // try x,y swapped
            {
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   iy][   ix]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                                 swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   iy][my-ix]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                 mirror_y(s[i]); swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-iy][   ix]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]);                 swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-iy][my-ix]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]); mirror_y(s[i]); swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            }
        } if (id[k]<0) return;          // fail

    for (ix=nx-1,j=id[0],k=3,i=1;i<6;i++)// find f3 so it share f0(ix=nx-1) edge
     if (us[i]<0)                       // only in unknonw yet surfaces
        {
        mx=s[i].nx-1;
        my=s[i].ny-1;
        if ((s[j].nx==s[i].nx)&&(s[j].ny==s[i].ny)) // try x,y matched
            {
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   ix][   iy]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]);                 break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   ix][my-iy]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]); mirror_y(s[i]); break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-ix][   iy]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                                 break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-ix][my-iy]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                 mirror_y(s[i]); break; }
            }
        if ((s[j].nx==s[i].ny)&&(s[j].ny==s[i].nx)) // try x,y swapped
            {
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   iy][   ix]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                 mirror_y(s[i]); swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   iy][my-ix]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                                 swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-iy][   ix]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]); mirror_y(s[i]); swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-iy][my-ix]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]);                 swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            }
        } if (id[k]<0) return;          // fail

    for (ix=nz-1,j=id[2],k=1,i=1;i<6;i++)// find f1 so it share f2(ix=nz-1) edge
     if (us[i]<0)                       // only in unknonw yet surfaces
        {
        mx=s[i].nx-1;
        my=s[i].ny-1;
        if ((s[j].nx==s[i].nx)&&(s[j].ny==s[i].ny)) // try x,y matched
            {
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   ix][   iy]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]);                 break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   ix][my-iy]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]); mirror_y(s[i]); break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-ix][   iy]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                                 break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-ix][my-iy]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                 mirror_y(s[i]); break; }
            }
        if ((s[j].nx==s[i].ny)&&(s[j].ny==s[i].nx)) // try x,y swapped
            {
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   iy][   ix]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                 mirror_y(s[i]); swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   iy][my-ix]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k;                                 swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-iy][   ix]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]); mirror_y(s[i]); swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            for (iy=0;iy<s[j].ny;iy++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[mx-iy][my-ix]){ iy=-1; break; } if (iy>=0){ id[k]=i; us[i]=k; mirror_x(s[i]);                 swap_xy(s[i]); break; }
            }
        } if (id[k]<0) return;          // fail
    i=0;
    // copy surfaces into volume matrix
    for (ix=0;ix<nx;ix++)
     for (iy=0;iy<ny;iy++)
      for (iz=0;iz<nz;iz++)
        {
        // interior points
        p.x=0.0;
        p.y=0.0;
        p.z=0.0;
        // surface points
        if (iz==   0) p=s[id[0]].dat[ix][iy];
        if (iz==nz-1) p=s[id[1]].dat[ix][iy];
        if (ix==   0) p=s[id[2]].dat[iz][iy];
        if (ix==nx-1) p=s[id[3]].dat[iz][iy];
        if (iy==   0) p=s[id[4]].dat[iz][ix];
        if (iy==ny-1) p=s[id[5]].dat[iz][ix];
        v.dat[ix][iy][iz]=p;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void draw(const surface &s) // render surface
    {
    int ix,iy,i;
    DWORD col[6]=   // colors per face
        {
        0x00202060,
        0x00202030,
        0x00206020,
        0x00203020,
        0x00602020,
        0x00302020
        };
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
        glColor4ubv((BYTE*)(&col[i]));
        for (ix=0;ix<s[i].nx;ix++)
         for (iy=1;iy<s[i].ny;iy++)
            {
            glVertex3fv((float*)&(s[i].dat[ix][iy  ]));
            glVertex3fv((float*)&(s[i].dat[ix][iy-1]));
            }
        for (ix=1;ix<s[i].nx;ix++)
         for (iy=0;iy<s[i].ny;iy++)
            {
            glVertex3fv((float*)&(s[i].dat[ix  ][iy]));
            glVertex3fv((float*)&(s[i].dat[ix-1][iy]));
            }
        }
    glEnd();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void draw(const volume &v)
    {
    int ix,iy,iz,i;
    // all points
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (ix=0;ix<v.nx;ix++)
     for (iy=0;iy<v.ny;iy++)
      for (iz=0;iz<v.nz;iz++)
       glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz]));
    glEnd();
    // surface edges for visual check if points are ordered as should
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (ix=     0,iy=     0,iz=     0;ix<v.nx;ix++) glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz])); glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (ix=     0,iy=     0,iz=v.nz-1;ix<v.nx;ix++) glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz])); glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (ix=     0,iy=v.ny-1,iz=     0;ix<v.nx;ix++) glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz])); glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (ix=     0,iy=v.ny-1,iz=v.nz-1;ix<v.nx;ix++) glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz])); glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (ix=     0,iy=     0,iz=     0;iy<v.ny;iy++) glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz])); glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (ix=     0,iy=     0,iz=v.nz-1;iy<v.ny;iy++) glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz])); glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (ix=v.nx-1,iy=     0,iz=     0;iy<v.ny;iy++) glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz])); glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (ix=v.nx-1,iy=     0,iz=v.nz-1;iy<v.ny;iy++) glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz])); glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (ix=     0,iy=     0,iz=     0;iz<v.nz;iz++) glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz])); glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (ix=     0,iy=v.nz-1,iz=     0;iz<v.nz;iz++) glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz])); glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (ix=v.nx-1,iy=     0,iz=     0;iz<v.nz;iz++) glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz])); glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (ix=v.nx-1,iy=v.nz-1,iz=     0;iz<v.nz;iz++) glVertex3fv((float*)&(v.dat[ix][iy][iz])); glEnd();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void cube(surface &s,const param &t)    // cube -> surface
    {
    point p;
    float *pp=(float*)&p;
    int iu,iv,nx,ny,nz,i,u,v;
    // count of points per axis
    nx=t[0].nx;
    ny=t[1].nx;
    nz=t[2].nx;
    if ((!nx)||(!ny)||(!nz)) return;
    // create 6 faces grid
    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
        if (i==0){ p.z=t[2].dat[   0]; u=0; v=1; } // z = first coordinate
        if (i==1){ p.z=t[2].dat[nz-1]; u=0; v=1; } // z = last coordinate
        if (i==2){ p.y=t[0].dat[   0]; u=0; v=2; } // y = first coordinate
        if (i==3){ p.y=t[0].dat[ny-1]; u=0; v=2; } // y = last coordinate
        if (i==4){ p.x=t[1].dat[   0]; u=2; v=1; } // x = first coordinate
        if (i==5){ p.x=t[2].dat[nx-1]; u=2; v=1; } // x = last coordinate
        s[i].allocate(t[u].nx,t[v].nx);         // allocate face resolution
        for (iu=0;iu<s[i].nx;iu++)              // process all cells
         for (iv=0;iv<s[i].ny;iv++)
            {
            pp[u]=t[u].dat[iu];
            pp[v]=t[v].dat[iv];
            s[i].dat[iu][iv]=p;
            }
        }        
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void cubic(surface &s,const param &t)   // hardcoded cubic curved object -> surface
    {
    point p;
    float *pp=(float*)&p;
    int ix,iy,iz,nx,ny,nz,i,j;

    // 3 hard coded cubic control points
    float cp[3][4][3]=  // [parameter][point][coordinate]
        {
        {{ 0.00,0.00,0.00 },
         { 0.50,0.50,0.00 },
         { 1.00,0.50,0.00 },
         { 1.50,0.00,0.00 }},
        {{ 0.00,0.00,0.00 },
         { 0.10,0.15,0.00 },
         { 0.15,0.30,0.00 },
         { 0.16,0.45,0.00 }},
        {{ 0.00,0.00,0.00 },
         { 0.00,0.10,0.15 },
         { 0.00,0.10,0.30 },
         { 0.00,0.00,0.45 }}
        };
    float ce[3][4][3];  // cubic coeficients
    float tx[4],ty[4],tz[4],d1,d2;
    for (ix=0;ix<3;ix++)
     for (iy=0;iy<3;iy++)
        {
        d1=0.5*(cp[ix][2][iy]-cp[ix][0][iy]);
        d2=0.5*(cp[ix][3][iy]-cp[ix][1][iy]);
        ce[ix][0][iy]=cp[ix][1][iy];
        ce[ix][1][iy]=d1;
        ce[ix][2][iy]=(3.0*(cp[ix][2][iy]-cp[ix][1][iy]))-(2.0*d1)-d2;
        ce[ix][3][iy]=d1+d2+(2.0*(-cp[ix][2][iy]+cp[ix][1][iy]));
        }

    // count of points per axis
    nx=t[0].nx;
    ny=t[1].nx;
    nz=t[2].nx;
    if ((!nx)||(!ny)||(!nz)) return;
    // allocate faces
    s[0].allocate(nx,ny);
    s[1].allocate(nx,ny);
    s[2].allocate(ny,nz);
    s[3].allocate(ny,nz);
    s[4].allocate(nz,nx);
    s[5].allocate(nz,nx);
    // process all points
    for (ix=0;ix<nx;ix++)
     for (iy=0;iy<ny;iy++)
      for (iz=0;iz<nz;iz++)
        {
        // compute t,t^2,t^3 per each parameter
        for (tx[0]=1.0,i=1;i<4;i++) tx[i]=tx[i-1]*t[0].dat[ix];
        for (ty[0]=1.0,i=1;i<4;i++) ty[i]=ty[i-1]*t[1].dat[iy];
        for (tz[0]=1.0,i=1;i<4;i++) tz[i]=tz[i-1]*t[2].dat[iz];
        // compute position as superposition of 3 cubics
        for (i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
            pp[i]=0.0;
            for (j=0;j<4;j++) pp[i]+=ce[0][j][i]*tx[j];
            for (j=0;j<4;j++) pp[i]+=ce[1][j][i]*ty[j];
            for (j=0;j<4;j++) pp[i]+=ce[2][j][i]*tz[j];
            }
        // copy posiiton to corresponding surfaces
        if (iz==   0) s[0].dat[ix][iy]=p;
        if (iz==nz-1) s[1].dat[ix][iy]=p;
        if (ix==   0) s[2].dat[iy][iz]=p;
        if (ix==nx-1) s[3].dat[iy][iz]=p;
        if (iy==   0) s[4].dat[iz][ix]=p;
        if (iy==ny-1) s[5].dat[iz][ix]=p;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**usage:** simple single form VCL app without any components

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>            // VCL stuff (ignore)
#pragma hdrstop             // VCL stuff (ignore)
#include "Unit1.h"          // VCL stuff (header of this window)
#include "gl_simple.h"      // my GL init (source included)
#include "parametric_grid.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init) // VCL stuff (ignore)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"    // VCL stuff (ignore)
TForm1 *Form1;              // VCL stuff (this window)
surface sur;                // 6 2D matrices (surfaces in any order/orientation before normalization)
volume vol;                 // 3D matrix (volume)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-0.9,-0.75,-2.0);
    glRotatef(45.0,0.5,0.5,0.0);

    glPointSize(4.0);
    glColor3f(0.1,0.5,0.7); draw(vol);
    glPointSize(1.0);
//  draw(sur);

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    // this is called on window startup
    gl_init(Handle);                // init OpenGL 1.0

    int i;
    param t;                        // source coordinates
/*
    t[0].allocate(5); i=0;
    t[0][i]=0.000; i++;
    t[0][i]=0.125; i++;
    t[0][i]=0.250; i++;
    t[0][i]=0.500; i++;
    t[0][i]=1.000; i++;

    t[1].allocate(5); i=0;
    t[1][i]=0.000; i++;
    t[1][i]=0.250; i++;
    t[1][i]=0.500; i++;
    t[1][i]=0.750; i++;
    t[1][i]=1.000; i++;

    t[2].allocate(6); i=0;
    t[2][i]=0.0; i++;
    t[2][i]=0.2; i++;
    t[2][i]=0.4; i++;
    t[2][i]=0.6; i++;
    t[2][i]=0.8; i++;
    t[2][i]=1.0; i++;
*/
  
    t[0].allocate(6); i=0;
    t[0][i]=0.0; i++;
    t[0][i]=0.2; i++;
    t[0][i]=0.4; i++;
    t[0][i]=0.6; i++;
    t[0][i]=0.8; i++;
    t[0][i]=1.0; i++;
    t[1].allocate(6); i=0;
    t[1][i]=0.0; i++;
    t[1][i]=0.2; i++;
    t[1][i]=0.4; i++;
    t[1][i]=0.6; i++;
    t[1][i]=0.8; i++;
    t[1][i]=1.0; i++;
    t[2].allocate(6); i=0;
    t[2][i]=0.0; i++;
    t[2][i]=0.2; i++;
    t[2][i]=0.4; i++;
    t[2][i]=0.6; i++;
    t[2][i]=0.8; i++;
    t[2][i]=1.0; i++;


//  cube(sur,t);
    cubic(sur,t);
    surface2volume(vol,sur);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // this is called before window exits
    gl_exit();                      // exit OpenGL
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // this is called on each window resize (and also after startup)
    gl_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // this is called whnewer app needs repaint
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is preview for code above:

[image: preview]

I debug by trying all combinations of mirror/swap for each surfac (first does not count as its used as is) and rendering the shared edges if they overlap exactly and tweaked the reordering of found faces until they did so the code should be working for any input (that connects)

Comment: I don't know how to thank you for the efforts involved, but if I understand you're trying to create a structured --regular-- grid. The unit cube was only an example. The faces I have are representative of a general surface patch in space. Look at this image https://images.app.goo.gl/PmADc6xxLWTppYbv8 I can assure that points of this image can be stored in three 3-D matrices (X(:,:,:) Y(:,:,:) Z(:,:,:)). The interior points are extrapolated with TFI but for this algorithm to operate the boundaries of the block must be filled with surface patches that are stored as 2-D X,Y,Z matrices.

Comment: All I have is six faces (arbitrary surface patches stored in 2-D matrices)  and who is connected to whom. I've thought, after the first face insertion, of comparing the corners of the first face inserted with the corners of the second face to be inserted (arbitrarily chosen from the neighbours of the first face). The position with minimum distance from corners is the right one. But this is painful because must be hand-coded and only for second insertion there are 4*4 possibilities. The third insertion will have 4*3 possibilities which depend on the preceding 4*4 possibilities.

Comment: Always 6 faces, because a 3D matrix has 6 faces.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not interested in obtaining the interior values of the volume, I've my routines for that. For now I need just to insert faces in the 3-D matrices in the correct order.

Comment: @RobPazzuzu7 I reedited my answer. The code simply sets the interrior points to `(0,0,0)` so if you would need interpolation you would need to encode it into it (just mimic the `cubic(sur,t);` function which I used to generate connected cubic surfaces). I already hit the 30000 char limit so no more code/text can be added ... Look for the `surface2volume(vol,sur)` function it does what you need. Beware I did not test different resolution of x,y,z with the new code so there still might be some hidden bugs I did not encounter (but I doubt it).

Comment: What a brilliant solution. You are a genius of a programmer. This is exactly what I needed. I've only 2 doubts on the code of surface2volume, if you are interested in 1) for (ix=0;ix<s[j].nx;ix++) if (s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i] .. why are you comparing all the points ? just comparing corners (edges endpoints) would not be sufficient? 2) s[j].dat[ix][iy]!=s[i].dat[   ix][   iy] taking into account floating point errors this can result in an error evalutaing if 2 points are the same..maybe evaluating distances would be better " if dist(edge1(0),edge2(0))>dist(edge1(0),edge2(nlast)) then reverse edge

Comment: @RobPazzuzu7 1. comparing corners instead of whole edges ... yes that should work (unless your surfaces are really weird) it didn't occur to me at a time I wrote that part of code however still feel safer with whole edge comparison ... 2. points are already compared with threshold distance see `bool point::operator!=(const point &a)` ... the threshold `d` is distance squared `return (d>0.001)` to avoid `sqrt` use